# How to generate the _grpc_pb.d.ts from a proto file for use with gRPC in a Node app?

Tags: node.js, typescript, grpc

Here is my `npm run protoc`, the line below will run:

```
./node_modules/protoc/protoc/bin/protoc --proto_path=proto --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:src/bin --grpc_out=src/bin --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=node_modules/grpc-tools/bin/grpc_node_plugin --ts_out=service=true:src/bin proto/authentication_service.proto
```

And it generates the following files:

```
authentication_service_grpc_pb.js
authentication_service_pb.d.ts
authentication_service_pb.js
authentication_service_pb_service.d.ts
authentication_service_pb_service.js
```

At one time I was able to get it to generate a **authentication_service_grpc_pb.d.ts** but with the config I saved above it does not. Can anyone help with what I am missing? Thanks!

Comment: What changed between that "one time" and now? Looks like the command gets the parameter to generate the files for js and ts just fine. Can you verify with the output that ts generation is working?

Comment: @zamber Honestly, the issue is that I may not have committed the correct version of the command. It took me awhile the first time to get it to generate the authentication_service_grpc_pb.d.ts. I have spent the last 2 days going through plugins that should generate the TS file for the authentication_service_grpc_pb.js but have not been successful. Nothing else has changed, I kept all things equal as the goal is to generate a new set for a new proto, testing with the existing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the ["How to use"](https://github.com/agreatfool/grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts#how-to-use) section of the documentation and note that generating the d.ts codes is done with a different executable:

```
npm install grpc_tools_node_protoc_ts --save-dev

# generate js codes via grpc-tools
grpc_tools_node_protoc \
--js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:./your_dest_dir \
--grpc_out=./your_dest_dir \
--plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_tools_node_protoc_plugin` \
-I ./proto \
./your_proto_dir/*.proto

# generate d.ts codes
protoc \
--plugin=protoc-gen-ts=./node_modules/.bin/protoc-gen-ts \
--ts_out=./your_dest_dir \
-I ./proto \
./your_proto_dir/*.proto
```

After writing this, that's not even the root of the problem (at least for this one particular generator). The executable in `bin/` is `protoc-gen-ts`.

When you're trying out different stuff make sure to version-control your attempts and clean out the output directory to have a reproducible environment.

Given all of this my best guess is that the `--ts-out` and `--js-out` flags cancel each other out and you'll have to run the generator once for each output type. Verify by trying it out. As a bonus you could try finding out if there's a `--verbose` flag to make your life easier :).

Comment: thanks for the help. Turns out I was missing **--grpc-ts_out=src/bin**. The above did not work for me either, it would get stuck during processing. The below works for everything I need and this time I made sure to save it:

`./node_modules/protoc/protoc/bin/protoc --proto_path=proto --js_out=import_style=commonjs,binary:src/bin --grpc_out=src/bin --grpc-ts_out=src/bin --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=node_modules/grpc-tools/bin/grpc_node_plugin --ts_out=src/bin proto/authentication_service.proto`